# Parsing a string into Date

Tags: javascript, date, globalization

I refer to [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) which has now been deprecated

Is there no built-in way to parse a date/time string as of now into a Date object in JavaScript?

Comment: Do you know about momment.js? Maybe it could cover your needs.

Comment: Refer to below question for more insight :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: @ianaya89 Thanks, but don't want to complicate matters with another library. I solve it at the backend with Python to parse and then output into ISO format so as to make it consistent for the frontend JavaScript.